# Textarea element does not expand 100% of its width

Tags: html, css, angular

I am learning Angular JS 8 in the process when I was going through implementing angular material library. I found that the Textarea Element is not expanding to 100% width

Thought it is Broswer issue but no I found same display in the Firefox browser also.

Tried using Boxsizing as well but did not avail anything.

```css
mat-card {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* <=iOS4, <= Android  2.3 */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* FF1+ */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Chrome, IE8, Opera, Safari 5.1*/
}
```

```html
<mat-card>
  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput rows='6' [(ngModel)]="enteredValue"> 
      </textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <br>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onAddPost()">Save Post</button>
</mat-card>

<p>{{ newPost }}</p>
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Eyckr_JffJdMRnOtR2dFHI3scx9qDATN/view?usp=sharing

Please find the above image which shows how i want my textarea to expand

Comment: Start by using your browser dev tools to go and figure out if your attempt at styling the textarea gets overwritten by a more specific rule.

Comment: created a code snippet of your cod. please tell s whats going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `width: 100%` for `mat-form-field` which is parent element for `textarea`.

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-form-field style="width: 100%">
      <textarea matInput rows = '6' [(ngModel)] = "enteredValue"> 
  </textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
   <br>
   <button
  mat-raised-button
  color ="primary"
 (click)="onAddPost()">Save Post</button>
</mat-card>

<p>{{ newPost }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your example, use style of mat-form-field instead of text-area

```
mat-form-field{
  width: 100%;
}
```

I would prefer to put a wrapper around with style `display: flex; flex-direction: column;`;, if there are multiple form fields

```
<mat-card>
  <section class="form-container">
    <mat-form-field>
      <textarea matInput rows='6' [(ngModel)]="enteredValue"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </section>
</mat-card>

.form-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: refer https://xng-breadcrumb.netlify.com. It has good usage of Angular material form fields

Comment: Dear Uday, What purposewill  the Wrapper serve when there are multiple fields ?

Comment: Hey Robin, wrapper may not be necessary here. But we tend to use <mat-card-title>, <mat-card-content> and <mat-card-footer> and if styled by it's wrapper, form fields alignment can be moved around easily whether it is inside <mat-card-content> or <mat-card>